# Is there a reason why when a React Native Modal is open, when heading to a new screen it stays in front of all screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am not sure why when using `React-Native` Modal component or `React-Navigation` Modal, both seems to have an opacity where it is in front of the screens.

1 - When modal is open I click on username to head to the next stack screen
2 - Screen changes in the background since I can see it as I have an opacity
3 - Model stays open without minimizing smoothly or sliding to the side for a new screen
4 - Tried hacky way of forcing a close before changing screens but looks very strange

If more code is needed please ask but my modal implementation is (will show React-Nativation):

```
  <RootStack.Group
    screenOptions={{
      presentation: "transparentModal",
      headerShown: false,
      gestureEnabled: true,
      ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS,
    }}
  >
    <RootStack.Screen
      name="Test"
      component={Test}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        contentStyle: {
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5)",
        },
      }}
      listeners={() => ({
        tabPress: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("1 is pressing");
        },
      })}
    />
  </RootStack.Group>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with my modal which prevents it from switching to a new screen completely without having that Modal be closed or still be in front of what is changing?

Thanks for all the hints and help

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, on the button press to first close modal and then to navigate to another page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did provide a button to close the modal before navigating. The weird effect I get is the background showing the screen change and the modal closing after

Comment: Although I am hoping not have the modal close. Much similar what is seen in the Reddit App where when you go back it will have the modal still open